# Sistema de login no checkea si existe el usuario

Tags: php

El problema es que se detiene la ejecución en la linea  `if( $row_count==0 )` y pasa al else.

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
    if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']) && ($granted=="true")) {
        $message = 'Ha ocurrido un error';
        $sql2= 'select id from users where email=\''. htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES). '\''; 
        $records = $conn->prepare($sql2);
        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $row_count = $result->num_rows;
        if( $row_count==0 ) {
            if($results = 0){
                $exists = "false";
            } else {
                $exists = "true";
            }
            $message = '';
            if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, user) VALUES (:email, :password, :user)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']);
            }
            if($_POST['password']==$_POST['confirm_password']) {
                $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
                $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
            } else {
                $error = 'password';
            }   
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $message = 'Successfully created new user';
            } else {
                if($error=="password"){
                    $message = 'Credentials does not match';
            } else {
                $message = 'Sorry there must have been an issue creating your account';
            }
            }
        } else {
            $error = 'exist';
            $message = 'Account alredy exist';
        }
    } else {
        $message = 'You don??t have permissions';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Pon un echo a tu variable `$sql2`, luego copias el query que te imprimirá para que lo pruebes en tu base de datos a ver si esta ejecutándose bien

Comment: esto es asignacion `if($results = 0){` debe ser comparacion `if($results == 0){` fuera de ello este `if - else` no hace nada ya que es`fetch assoc`,  no existe un `0` en `$result` solo un `$result[
"id"]` aparte si `$row_count` devuelve al menos un resultado es obvio que existe! tienes que eliminar este `if - else` o corregirlo por `if($result[
"id"])`